# C++ | Как сделать что бы пользователь смог по желанию покинуть код

Tags: c++, циклы

Что бы выйти из цикла, нужно ввести 0, если что то другое, то продолжается. Но когда вводишь букву, то цикл выключается, как это предотвратить?

```
  int main() 
    {
        while (true) 
            {
            long long mul = 1;
            int rangeBegin = 10;
            int rangeEnd = 99;
            do {
                if (rangeBegin % 2 == 0 && rangeBegin % 5 == 0)
                {
                    mul *= rangeBegin;
                }
                rangeBegin++;
            } while (rangeBegin < rangeEnd);
            cout << "Multiplication= " << mul << endl;
            int val;
            cout << "Do you want to exit the program?" << endl;
            cin >> val;
            if (val == 0)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Проверить состояние потока, если `faail` - сбросить, очистить буфер, повторить ввод...

Answer (score 0):

cin предполагает преобразование типов, а поскольку val имеет тип целое число, при преобразование возвращает 0 (точно также как и atoi)

Измените тип val на символьный/строковый. например так:

```
        char val;
        cout << "Do you want to exit the program?" << endl;
        cin >> val;
        if (val == '0')
        {
            break;
        }
```